# action when entering/exiting the block in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

the blocks do not execute the code "when entering/exiting", maybe also in other conditions.

To fix this, you have to add a "delay" block, and only after that everything starts working. Actually, the question is: how can I fix this, or am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: You are 100% not using (or understanding) the setup correctly. Are you, by any chance, using a SelectOutput before your test code blocks? Else, pls demo an example setup showing how it is not working, see some tips for good questions here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: @Benjamin
To clarify, I have a source block in which the following code is written in the "on exit" field: "ped.parameter1 = true", followed by SelecOutput. In this case, it will not work, and you need to add a "delay" block. I have visited the help several times, but there is nothing written about it, and the standard description implies that this code must be 100% executed before entering SelectOutput

Comment: @Felipe Yes, this explained the behavior of the model. I apologize for asking questions that have already been answered: it is difficult to search for information in English when you speak only another language.